# How to allocate a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, stdvector

I use `dfs` in a question but I have not called `dfs` in the main till now and my program is crashing. Recently I was programming in `c` and now I switched to `cpp`. So I am new to `cpp`.

I know where I did mistake in vectors please tell what can I improve.
I know vector can increase there size automatically.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
const int MAX = 100000;

bool visited[MAX] = { 0 };
int intime[MAX];
int outtime[MAX];

int timer = 0;
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> graph, int v)
{
    visited[v] = true;
    timer++;
    intime[v] = timer;
    vector<int>::iterator it = graph[v].begin();
    while (it != graph[v].end()) {
        if (visited[*it] == false)
        {
            dfs(graph, *it);
        }
        it++;
    }
    ++timer;
    outtime[v] = timer;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> graph;
    graph[1].push_back(2);
    graph[1].push_back(3);
    graph[3].push_back(6);
    graph[2].push_back(4);
    graph[2].push_back(5);
    graph[5].push_back(7);
    graph[5].push_back(8);
    graph[5].push_back(9);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `graph[1]` after `vector<vector<int>> graph;` is undefined behavior, due to non-existent element access.

Comment: i am declaring a 2d vector

Comment: that is a vector of vector

Comment: @humblefool you're declaring **an empty 2d vector** then accessing non-existing elements.

Comment: @humblefool Yes, I am not arguing that it isn't. The problem is that `graph[1]` tries to access non existant element in `graph`, and due to that, it invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem on your own? Where exactly is the program crashing? Is there any error message involved?

Comment: here row size doesn't matter because they can expand according to need?

Comment: sorry mam i am fool @NicoHaase `:)`

Comment: @humblefool "_here row size doesn't matter they can expand according to need_" Only when using `push_back`, `emplace_back`, or `resize`. Consider re-reading the documentation of [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Comment: got it sir @AlgirdasPreidžius

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program crashes because of accessing unallocated memory. The correct way is

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph(5); // allocates 5 rows of vector of vectors
                                   ^^^^
```

Secondly, in C++ array indexing starting from `0` to `n-1`. Therefore you need

```
graph[0].push_back(2);  // element at (0,0)
graph[0].push_back(3);  // element at (0,1)
graph[1].push_back(6);  // element at (1,0)
graph[1].push_back(4);  // element at (1,1)
....
```

---

Alternatively, you could initialize directly the *vector of vectors* using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> graph
{
    {2, 3},   // first row of vector
    {4, 5},   // second row of vector
    {6},      // third row of vector
    {7, 8, 9} // forth row of vector
};
```

or [emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) each row of vector to the *vector of vectors*.

```
using Row = std::vector<int>;
std::vector<Row> graph;
graph.emplace_back(Row{ 2, 3 });
graph.emplace_back(Row{ 4, 5 });
graph.emplace_back(Row{ 6 });
graph.emplace_back(Row{7, 8, 9});
```

Answer (score 2):

The the size of the vector is zero in the way you declared it.

What you can do is declare the vector with a size.

```
int v = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<int>>graph(v);
graph[1].push_back(2);
```

This will work.